# Wacom Tablet - xsetwacom Area command causes no change

Tags: tablet, wacom

I've been trying to use the `xsetwacom --set 16 Area` command to change the area that my Wacom Intuos tablet can operate on (16 is the stylus device).

When I plug in the tablet the default area is

```
xsetwacom --get 16 Area
0 0 15200 9500
```

I used the command `xsetwacom --set 16 Area 0 0 7510 4750` ideally to reduce the dimensions in which the tablet can move the cursor by a factor of 2. But no change occurs and the tablet can still affect my entire screen.

If it matters:

```
xsetwacom --version
0.24.0
```

Comment: how did you resolve this?